# express: getting the URL of the running instance globally

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express 4.x and I want to know if there is a way to get the URL (for instance localhost:7777 or mydomain.com) during the run-time?

I have several requests, where I need to return images saved on the same server with the full URL, but the IP address / port is changing, therefore I would like a solution, where I can save the URL globally. (not within a get/... request)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you access the app instance:

```
var app = express();

 ....

app.address() //address
app.port() // port
```